# How to check if a specific application is enabled or disabled in shopify theme customization

Tags: rest, graphql, shopify

Suppose I have an app, a merchant has some subscription and the app shows up in Theme -> Customization, There is option to enable or disable app for the theme. How do I get to know if the merchant has enabled my app or not? For better understanding, look at this image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUssB.png)

I tried searching for GraphQL API requests, REST API, but could not find how to get this info. Some themes have stored this in assets schema setting json file, but not necessarily every theme stores this info at that place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you have to hit url using REST API for the `config/settings_data.json` file of the main theme and there you can find `blocks` in `current`. where you can check if the disabled state is true or false. [More Details](https://community.shopify.com/c/hydrogen-headless-and-storefront/detecting-app-embed-blocks/td-p/1516195)